# Object is undefined even thought it was created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can someone explain why this object is giving me undefined even thought the console.log just gave me a full object?

```
    export default function ListForms() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  // Get the ID from the URL
  const { id } = useParams();

  // Hooks
  const [forms, setForms] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const objectID = new Object();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create an scoped async function in the hook
    async function fetchData() {
      var forms_response = await api
        .get(`/user/list/${id}`)
        .then(function(forms_response) {
          setForms(forms_response.data);

          const id_response = Object.keys(forms_response.data).forEach(function(
            item
          ) {
            var formID = forms_response.data[item].id;
            var answer = api
              .get(`/answerNumber/${formID}`)
              .then(function(answer) {
                objectID[item] = answer.data.answerNumber;
              });
          });
          console.log(objectID);
          setIsLoading(true);
        });
    }

    // Execute the created function directly
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // function getAnswer (formID) {
  //   var answer = api.get(`/answerNumber/${formID}`)
  //       .then(function(answer) {
  //         console.log(answer.data.answerNumber);
  //         setResponse (answer.data.answerNumber);
  //       });
  // }
  return isLoading ? (
    <div>
      <Tab />
      <Container>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          {Object.keys(forms).map((item, i) => (
            <Grid item xl={4} lg={4} md={4} sm={6} xs={12} zeroMinWidth>
              <CardForm
                title={forms[i].title}
                description={forms[i].description}
                numberOfAnswers={objectID[i]}
              ></CardForm>
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <h1></h1>
  );
}
```

What happens is that the console.log prints out this:

```
{}
​
0: 2
​
1: 3
​
2: 4
​
3: 1
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Which is right, but when I try to to use the `objectID[i]` it gives me undefined (I tried casting it to string to be sure). I really don't know what else to do and even spent a whole morning with other 2 friends trying to solve this, keep in mind we are all learning React and we are only using React hooks, not classes.

Comment: Isn't that object created and populated asynchronously? If so, it will not be ready yet at the time you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. `const objectID = new Object();` will declare a new `objectId` every time the functional component gets re-rendered. You want it to be persistent. So either `useState` to save it or [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Something like this `const objectID = useRef({})`

2. Your template will get re-rendered when one of the dependencies changes (states, props). You are updating `objectID`, but don't update any state, as such no rendered is done.

You should be able to fix this, if you update loading to true when all the calls are done.